# What is the best way to mock entity framework model in .NET CORE?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, mocking, moq

I am new at entity framework. I have a data context with my models. We have used DB first approach to create that model. I have performed an add operation and a get operation on this model. Now I want to include these operations in my Nunit test. We are using **moq** for that. I am not yet considering to create any interface for the DataContext.
I have some experience in mocking database tables and command. We used to create a dummy table and add dummy data in it using `Mock<>` How are things done in entity framework?

How can I `Setup` a model and add dummy data in it?
Or is this not how we do in entity framework?
Can anyone help me in solving this?

I'm attaching sample code of my operation.

Add entries to DB:

```
using (MyContext context= new MyContext())
{
   Table table = new storage;
   table.id=123;
   table.value="dummyValue";
   context.table.Add(storage);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Get DB entries:

```
using (MyContext context= new MyContext())
{
   foreach (var table in context.Table)
   {
      Sconfig config = new Sconfig ();
      config.id = table.id;
      config.value=table.value;
      lst.Add(table);
   }
}
return lst;
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? How EF Core works?

Comment: I have tested the above mentioned code with an actual database. Now I want to include that code in my Nunit test case using moq. That is what I'm trying to do right now.

Comment: I didnt like the idea of having to mock out the data structure separately. I wanted to only have to mock out what data exists to run more comprehensive Unit Tests on the actual functionality. So i came across this project [Here](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/doomed-databases) which creates and deletes a database when i run my unit tests. this used XUnit, and a Postgres database. so it may be outside what you are using. but could be a route to go.

Comment: If your use cases are like the sample code, I'd probably look at the MS in-memory provider. Because you're new-ing the db context in your code rather than injecting it, provided the db context options are exactly the same for each construction, the state will persist between instances. Remember to change the database name in the db context options between tests if they are true unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this methods in your repository Test:

```
    private static DbContextOptions<MyContext> GetOptionsBuilder(string 
    dataBaseInMemoryName)
    {
         return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
         .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: dataBaseInMemoryName)
         .Options;
    }

    private void GenerateStubDataInMemory(MyContext context)
    {
        // Insert seed data into the database using one instance of the context
        context.Entity.Add(new Entity(Value1, Value2, Value3,...)
    }
```

And then in your test should be like this:

```
    public async Task Should_Find_Somehing_By_Filter()
    {
        private DbContextOptions<MyContext> optionsBuilder;
        optionsBuilder = GetOptionsBuilder("Find_Somehing_By_Filter");

        using (context = new MyContext(optionsBuilder, 
        httpContextAccessor.Object))
        {
            //Arrange
            GenerateStubDataInMemory(context);

            _repository = new Repository(context);

            //Action
            var result = await _repository.FindSomehingByFilter("Filter");

            //Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal(context.Table.FirstOrDefault().Property, 
            result.Property );
        }
    }
```